# In python, how would I turn multiple user inputs into a str or a list?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on a simple hangman game program, so the user inputs a letter as a guess. How would I put these letters into a list?

```
while not game_over:
  guess = input("Guess a letter. ")
  for pos in range(len(chosen_word)):
    letter = chosen_word[pos]
    if letter == guess:
      display[pos] = letter
  print(display)
  if display.count("_") == 0:
    print("Game over. ")
    game_over = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the dict display after the fact, using a for loop:

```
displayList = []
for i in display.values():
  displayList.append(i)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
displayList = [i for i in display.values()]
```

More info about that:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp

Or in the while loop by replacing `display[pos] = letter` with:
`displayList.append(letter)`

Answer (score 0):

```
guesses = []

while not game_over:
  guess = input("Guess a letter. ")
  guesses.extend(guess)
```

Given inputs of `a` and `b`, this produces a `guesses` list like ['a', 'b'].

Comment: Please don't use snippets for languages other than Javascript. Their purpose is to ask the browser to try to run the code, and that doesn't work for other languages.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the string to a list using `list()`:

```
guess = input("Guess a letter. ")
g1 = list(guess)
print(g1)

input: hi
output:['h', 'i']
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with something very similar to this.